# updating page value in List.js jquery library

Tags: jquery

I am using Jquery `List.js` library. As list.js Library have no option to dynamically change the number of records on a page, so I am trying to update page value dynamically through on change function. Problem is, value is passing correctly and it is shown in the console, but the list is not updating on the back end. The code I have tried is

```
   var x = $(function()
     {
     //rows are the id of drop down selection
         $('#rows').change(function(){
          console.log($(this).val());
          $(this).val();
       });
     });

    //default value is set if nothing selected
    if(!$.isEmptyObject( x ))
        x=10;

     var options = {
        valueNames: [ 'territory', 'territory_id'],
             page: x,
            plugins: [
               ListPagination({}
            )]
    };

    var contactList = new List('my-cool-sortable-table-wrapper', options);
    contactList.sort('territory', { order: 'asc' });
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: In your comment for the if-statement you are saying "default value is set if nothing selected", but what you are doing is setting the value to 10 i something is selected.

Comment: ignore this line, suppose i change the value , value is passed and it is shown in console but list is not updated. Whats the reason ?

Comment: can you give us the html list as well?

Comment: <label>Show 
                    <select name="rows" id="rows" size="1" >      
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                                    <option value="50">50</option>
                                    <option value="100">100</option>
                                    <option value="500">500</option>
                    </select> entries</label>

Comment: @Zorken17 please reply  ??

Comment: I am working on it

Comment: Check my code below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing to update the list, that's why you don't see the changes.
The documentation states that you need to update the object after change, object.update().

**Please see my code below:**

```
var x = 10

$('#rows').change(function() {
  x = $(this).val();

  updateList(x);
})

var options = {
  valueNames: ['territory', 'territory_id'],
  page: x,
  plugins: [
    ListPagination({})
  ]
};

var contactList = new List('my-cool-sortable-table-wrapper', options);
contactList.sort('territory', { order: 'asc' });

function updateList(x) {
  contactList.page = x;
  contactList.update()
}
```

Comment: Can i download the table data  through some built in functionality of List.js ?? 
i tried but not found

Comment: What do you mean by downloading table data? List.js is only a list presentation framework.

Comment: i want to download the report, which i have shown through list.js, any downloading option in list.js ??

Comment: You need to build you own "download function". Link.js is only for presenting lists.